# How do i display data from API using the ID?

Tags: php, html, api

I can now display the correct ID for each row of data in my URL. But now i am looking to display it in another screen.
I am struggling to figure out how to pull the data such as "player" or "Team" from the ID initially retrieved.
I am looking to display this data in a table in the GameInfo page.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

For example:

1. My Get for match results

==========================

```
   public function getMatchInfo() {
    $url = $this->buildUrl('scores/events.json? 
    key=Ka88B6jZrxO8dDQt&secret=L233yXpNCWQDZyxJIGSkNbjeI8nWLdqw&id=1"');
    return $this->makeRequest($url);
 }
```

Here i have to specify the ID which is annoying because the IDs change from game to game.
Is there a way i can edit to pull the ID from my index page? From the index page it displays the current "Live Games", and i click a link which opens the "Game Info" page, which is where i want to pull data from the API.

2. Index.php

======================

```
   <?php
   include 'config.php';
   include 'functions.php';
   include 'myapp.php';

  $Api = new LivescoreApi();
  $data = $Api->getLiveScores();
  $timezone = 'Europe/Istanbul';
?>

<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" 
    href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
    integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" 
    crossorigin="anonymous">
   </head>
   <body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <table class="table table-bordered">
                    <tr class="table-info">
                        <th>KO</th>
                        <th>Time</th>
                        <th>Home</th>
                        <th>Score</th>
                        <th>Away</th>
                    </tr>
                        <?php foreach ($data['data']['match'] as $_match) { ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td><?= convert($_match['scheduled'], $timezone) ?></td>
                            <td><?= $_match['time'] ?></td>
                            <td style="text-align: right;"><?= $_match['home_name'] ?></td>
                            <td style="text-align: center;"><?= $_match['score'] ?></td>
                            <td><?= $_match['away_name'] ?></td>
                            <td style="text-align: right;"><a href="gameInfo.php"> Game 
                             information </a><?= $_match['id'] ?></td>

                        </tr>
                        <?php } ?>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
   </body>
 </html>
```

3. GameInfo.php

=================

```
<tr class="table-info">
                    <h2 style="text-align: center;"> Game Info </h2>
                        <th>Player Name</th>
                        <th>Event</th>
                        <th>Time</th>
                        
                        
                        
                    </tr>
                    
                        <?php foreach ($data['data']['event'] as 
                        $_event){ ?>
                        <tr>
                            
                            <td style="text-align: center;"><?= 
                             $_event['player'] ?></td>
                            <td style="text-align: center;"><?= 
                             $_event['event'] ?></td>
                            <td style="text-align: center;"><?= 
                             $_event['time'] ?></td>
```

Answer (score 3):

Quite possible that I don't understand your question. Create a form so that the id is sent in the `$_GET["id"]` variable?

Comment: Well i mean, when i click the "gameInfo.php" link  on any of my rows of data, and it redirects me to that page, i would like to pull information soley for that rows id. What do you mean by a form?

Comment: In that case, if you're building a set of links from your array `$data["data"]["match"]` then just build each link as `<a href="gameInfo.php?id=<?=$_match['id']?>">Game information</a>`

Comment: andt then in my new screen, how would i call the id to display the correct info? i can see in the URL taht it gets the right ID but wont display information

Answer (score 3):

I think you just want to pass the ID you already have to the function?

```
public function getMatchInfo() {
    if(isset($_GET['id']){
        $id = $_GET['id']
    } //this check entirely optional, but I'd do it
    else{
        $id = 1; //or some other default you want, or error handling here
    }
    $url = $this->buildUrl('scores/events.json? 
    key=Ka88B6jZrxO8dDQt&secret=L233yXpNCWQDZyxJIGSkNbjeI8nWLdqw&id='.$id);
    return $this->makeRequest($url);
 }
```

## Index.php

```
<?php
   include 'config.php';
   include 'functions.php';
   include 'myapp.php';

  $Api = new LivescoreApi();
  $data = $Api->getLiveScores();
  $timezone = 'Europe/Istanbul';
?>

<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" 
    href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
    integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" 
    crossorigin="anonymous">
   </head>
   <body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <table class="table table-bordered">
                    <tr class="table-info">
                        <th>KO</th>
                        <th>Time</th>
                        <th>Home</th>
                        <th>Score</th>
                        <th>Away</th>
                    </tr>
                        <?php foreach ($data['data']['match'] as $_match) { ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td><?= convert($_match['scheduled'], $timezone) ?></td>
                            <td><?= $_match['time'] ?></td>
                            <td style="text-align: right;"><?= $_match['home_name'] ?></td>
                            <td style="text-align: center;"><?= $_match['score'] ?></td>
                            <td><?= $_match['away_name'] ?></td>
                            <td style="text-align: right;"><a href="gameInfo.php?id=<?= $_match['id'] ?>"> Game 
                             information </a><?= $_match['id'] ?></td>

                        </tr>
                        <?php } ?>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
   </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: That has helped me pass the id which is great but now i need to reflect that in my "gameInfo.php" screen. Which i have added above.

Comment: When i do a get on the returned url "http://ls.local/gameInfo.php?id=203091" i get no data back

Answer (score 0):

So i figured out the answer to my updated question.
I didnt add the "isSet()" check originally.
I did that now and I also was missing braces.
The joys of not using an IDE for code I guess.